# UICollectionView with CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout crashes on scroll up and down

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, ios9, xcode8

I created a **UICollectionView** using **CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout**, because i wanted to have separate Header for **UICollectionView** and its sections. It is showing data successfully, but when i scroll up or down and as soon as it touches to top or bottom boundary it crashes, giving following error, I simply want separate Headers for collection view and its sections like we have in UITableView. If someone can help resolve this issue or point some alternative.

> 2016-12-06 11:50:51.881 TestStickyHeader[899:18365] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.5.2/UICollectionViewData.m:445
>   2016-12-06 11:50:51.929 TestStickyHeader[899:18365] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout attributes for supplementary item at index path ( {length = 2, path = 9 - 0}) changed from  indexPath: {9, 0} zIndex: 1024 valid: YES kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader to  indexPath: {9, 0} zIndex: 1024 valid: YES kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader without invalidating the layout'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104cbb34b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010471c21e objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104cbf442 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
>       3   Foundation                          0x00000001042b2e4d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
>       4   UIKit                               0x00000001063f5c3b __45-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke + 1436
>       5   UIKit                               0x00000001063f5093 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 2984
>       6   UIKit                               0x00000001063f835e -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForCellsInRect:validateLayout:] + 170
>       7   UIKit                               0x0000000106392909 -[UICollectionView _computePrefetchCandidatesForVisibleBounds:futureVisibleBounds:prefetchVector:notifyDelegateIfNeeded:] + 134
>       8   UIKit                               0x0000000106392877 -[UICollectionView _computePrefetchCandidatesForVelocity:notifyDelegateIfNeeded:] + 214
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010639278d -[UICollectionView _prefetchItemsForVelocity:maxItemsToPrefetch:invalidateCandidatesOnDirectionChanges:] + 934
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010639baa7 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 717
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000105b12f50 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
>       12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001058c5cc4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
>       13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001058b9788 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
>       14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001058b9606 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>       15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105847680 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
>       16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105874767 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001057cfb97 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 611
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c4d964 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c4d5f3 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c4d17a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 250
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c44f01 __CFRunLoopRun + 2065
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c44494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>       23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109e38a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
>       24  UIKit                               0x0000000105a4e964 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       25  TestStickyHeader                    0x0000000103d9411f main + 111
>       26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b44c68d start + 1
>       27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException